# Find all sets doesn't contain any sub sets

Tags: algorithm, list, set

I have a problem and I'm researching the fastest algorithm to find a set that is subset of original set (S) and doesn't contain any subsets (S1, ... Sn) of S. The set I want to find can contain some elements of `Si` but doesn't contain the whole.

For example, `original set`: S = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), S1 = (1, 2), S2 = (1, 3)
=> `longest set`: (2, 3, 4, 5); `other sets`: (1, 4, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (1, 4),...

Anybody can give me a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Give more examples of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

### Bad news

Consider the problem of choosing which elements to NOT include.

If we choose to NOT include element 1, we satisfy the constraints for S1 and S2.

If we choose to NOT include element 2, we satisfy the constraints for S1.

If we choose to NOT include element 3, we satisfy the constraints for S1 and S3.

So 1 gives {S1,S2}, 2 gives {S1}, 3 gives {S3}.

Your problem can be expressed as finding the minimum number of elements to NOT include such that the union of the satisfied sets (e.g. {S1,S2}) covers all of the given sets.

This is exactly the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is NP complete.

### Good news

In practice, you will probably do quite well by simply choosing the elements to NOT include based on whichever ends up covering the most sets.

This is an easy to implement greedy algorithm (although it will not always give the optimal answer).